# Correct interpretation of raster values - bulk estimates

Tags: soilgrids

We are analyzing soil types in order to find suitable sites for afforestation. We would like to know as much as possible about their:

1. Soil pH in KCl
2. Cation exchange capacity
3. Available soil water capacity
4. Organic carbon stock

SoilGrids rasters we downloaded are: `TAXNWRB`, `PHIKCL_M_sl6`, `OCSTHA_M_100cm`, `CECSOL_M_sl6`, `BDRICM_M`, `AWCh1_M_sl6`, `AWCh3_M_sl6`

We found the chapter explaining how the estimates were calculated:

> "We generate predictions at seven standard depths for all numeric soil
>   properties (except for depth to bedrock and soil organic carbon
>   stock): 0 cm, 5 cm, 15 cm, 30 cm, 60 cm, 100 cm and 200 cm, as per the
>   GlobalSoilMap specifications Arrouays et al. (2014). In vertical
>   dimension we predict at point support i.e. exactly for given depth,
>   while in horizontal space the predictions match the support of
>   covariates. Bulk estimates of values for standard depth intervals,
>   e.g. 0–5 cm, can be further derived by taking an average any pair of
>   upper and lower absolute depths, or a weighted average from multiple
>   depths." (Source:
>   https://github.com/ISRICWorldSoil/SoilGrids250m/wiki/Target-soil-variables)

The stage where we stopped is the understanding the calculation behind the next layers: `PHIKCL_M_sl6`, `CECSOL_M_sl6`, `AWCh1_M_sl6` and `AWCh3_M_sl6`.

The thing is, we need the bulk estimate for those layers at depths up to, for instance, 1 meter, but not the values at specific depth. How can we get those values? Should we simply calculate the average between upper and lower depth, like:
`(PHIKCL_M_sl1 + PHIKCL_M_sl6)/2` to get the bulk estimation for the depth range up to 1 meter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes. The numerical integration within the depth interval is the recommended method. You can read the details in the [SoilGrids 2017 article](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0169748) (Section Methods and materials):

> We generated predictions at seven standard depths for all numeric soil properties (except for depth to bedrock and soil organic carbon stock): 0 cm, 5 cm, 15 cm, 30 cm, 60 cm, 100 cm and 200 cm, following the vertical discretisation as specified in the GlobalSoilMap specifications [17]. Averages over (standard) depth intervals, e.g. 0–5 cm or 0–30 cm, can be derived by taking a weighted average of the predictions within the depth interval using numerical integration, such as the trapezoidal rule: